# OpenLDAP Administrative limit exeeded

Tags: openldap, ldap

I know there are limits in LDAP queries, therefore I setup a user without limits. But even so I'm facing "Administrative Limit exceeded" error.

I include below an extract of the database configuration. I'm using the user cn=checkrepl,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=es.

```
esauro@ubuntu:~$ ldapsearch -x -W -D 'cn=admin,cn=config' -b 'cn=config' -h openldap1 'olcDatabase={1}hdb'
Enter LDAP Password: 
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=config> with scope subtree
# filter: olcDatabase={1}hdb
# requesting: ALL
#

# {1}hdb, config
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=domain,dc=es
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymou
 s auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=es" write by dn.subtree="cn=Managers,dc=domain,
 dc=es" read by * none
olcAccess: {2}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {3}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=es" write by * read
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcLimits: {2}dn="cn=checkrepl,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=es" time.soft=unlimited time
 .hard=unlimited size.soft=unlimited size.hard=unlimited
olcSizeLimit: size=100000 size.unchecked=100000
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
olcMonitoring: TRUE
olcDbCacheSize: 200000
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcDbConfig: {0}set_cachesize 0 536870912 0
olcDbConfig: {1}set_lk_max_objects 1500
olcDbConfig: {2}set_lk_max_locks 1500
```

However whenever I query the directory and, if the result is big, I get the error, no matter whether or not I include the flags to limit the time and the size of the query.

```
esauro@ubuntu:~$ ldapsearch -z 40 -l 1000 -x -W -D 'cn=checkrepl,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=es' -b 'dc=domain,dc=es' -h openldap1 'uid=al*' dn
Enter LDAP Password: 
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=domain,dc=es> with scope subtree
# filter: uid=al*
# requesting: dn 
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 11 Administrative limit exceeded

# numResponses: 1
```

I'm using ldap-utils (version 2.4.23 and 2.4.28) as client and openldap (2.4.23) as server

**EDIT:** Another excerpt from the config including the indexes:

```
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcDbIndex: uid eq,pres,sub
olcDbIndex: memberUid,uniqueMember eq
olcDbIndex: uidNumber,gidNumber eq,pres
olcDbIndex: sambaSID,sambaPrimaryGroupSID eq
olcDbIndex: sambaGroupType,sambaSIDList eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN,entryUUID eq
olcDbIndex: ou,cn eq
olcDbIndex: mail,maildrop eq
```

**EDIT 2:** This exact configuration (Copy&Paste) is working perfectly in another LDAP using a more recent version of LDAP.

Comment: How are `sizelimit` and `timelimit` configured on your server?

Comment: The configuration is in the extract I posted. olcSizeLimit: size=100000 size.unchecked=100000. The limit for the user is explicitly set to unlimited in both case!

Answer (score 1):

You have `olcDbCacheSize: 200000` (and a 512MB cache) indicating you may have a high number of directory entries.

You have `size.unchecked=100000` which places limits on queries for attributes with no 
indexes.

There are no `olcDbIndex` attributes in your config [extract], so there <strike>are</strike> *may* be no indexes for searching.

If you have more than 100,000 entries, your search will need a full directory scan, and exceed its default `size.unchecked` limits, regardless of how many actually match `uid=al*`.

You *really* need indexes. Try running with `olcLoglevel: stats index`, and check your syslog configuration to make sure the facility (local4 is default) goes somewhere useful.
Add indexes, including *at least* your common queries, and sub(string) indexes for uid, and run `slapindex -v` to update, `slapd` should not be running during the index generation.

http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/tuning.html

Comment: I have indexes. It is just an excerpt of the configuration, not all configuration. The query "uid=al*" should return about 40k entries, however more important is that rootdn can perform that query.

Comment: Limits (and ACLs) are not applied to the rootdn. Do you have `sub` or `subinitial` indexes on uid? What indexes do you have in place? Check your `/var/lib/ldap` directory for a *large* `uid.bdb` index file. Did you bulk import using `slapadd`?

Comment: I modified the entry including the indexes configuration. There is a 28M file uid.bdb in the ldap directory. Yes we use slapadd to import users.

Comment: I estimate `pres,eq,sub` indexes at ~256 bytes per-entry, that tells me you only have ~110k entries indexed. Unless your uids mostly begin with "al", it doesn't look like your indexed data is complete (I guess ~2M entries). Did `slapindex` run to completion without error after `slapadd`? If you changed any `olcDbIndex` config a subsequent restart of `slapd` before completion of background indexing could explain this too. I suggest stop/`slapindex -v`/start as the next step.

Comment: There are about 154k entries in directory and most of them (76.5k) begin with 'al' (I thought there were less entries starting with this substring).